# Determine actual public interface for a Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, trace

I have a Ruby gem that uses some internal, closed source libraries. I'm trying to build an interface compatible drop-in off of open libraries for one application in particular. This application only uses a subset of the library's public interface, so I don't need rewrite all of it.

I need to figure out what subset of classes the application actually calls so I know what I need to target for reimplementation. If I could instrument the calls during the the app's test runs, maybe I could look at the stack and see where the points of entry into the library are.

Does something like this exist, or do I need to write this myself?

Comment: Perhaps not exactly what you're looking for, but [Scientist](https://github.com/github/scientist) is a tool written specifically for methodically replacing parts of your Ruby infrastructure.

Comment: Yeah, not exactly what I'm looking for, but could be useful elsewhere in this project, so thanks!